# Can I 'pretend' I have a one-to-one producer-consumer problem instead of many-to-one?

Tags: multithreading, producer-consumer

I suspect this is a relatively obscure and specific question, so I'll try to be as clear as possible in describing it. All of my code is being done in C++ in pursuit of a computer vision project.

1. I have a primary thread, acting as a consumer.
2. This thread generates N producers that need to use a hodgepodge of proprietary software to acquire images from their camera buffers. Each of them does a quick conversion to cv::Mats before passing them along to the consumer for actual processing.

Here's where I trip up. **Is it possible to twist this multiple-producer-single-consumer problem into a set of N single-producer-single-consumer problems? Something like this?**

```
while(
0 == pipeBuffer1.read_available() ||
0 == pipeBuffer2.read_available() ||
...
0 == pipeBuffern.read_available()
) { //wait
}

// do a fifo pop for each buffer and fuse them all into a single frame
```

I ask because, by my best understanding, I can transition over to lock-free ring buffers in the single-single version of the problem. I can't immediately see a reason why I *can't* treat my design issue this way, but my experience is slim to nil with multithreading and I figured I might as well ask before wasting my time trying to implement something that can't work.

Comment: I don't see where the producers enter into this question at all. You have a "consumer" that does some work, and you are asking whether it is possible to have more than one of them working concurrently. The answer depends entirely on whether the concurrent consumers would have to operate on any shared resources. What (if anything) do they share?

Comment: I should have been more specific at the processing part. I am actually trying to fuse the images I get from each camera with some registration/rectification I'm playing around with that I've got a better handle on. My main concern is with trying to get multiple streaming video feeds into that part of my program while A. making sure my consumer doesn't accidentally take too many frames from any one producing thread (leaving empty spots or weird flickers in the final product) and B. not wasting my time trying to use lock-free when it won't do anything or will break using it like this.